# How to show the Action Buttons once the user reaches end of the iframe Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an Iframe and it have a scroll bar now the thing is I need to show two action buttons once the user reaches the end of the iframe by scrolling..
The use case is I need to display the two action buttons when the user reaches the end of the iframe.

Comment: Could you please try and explain your question more? Maybe post the HTML. What is the porpose?

Comment: Okay I have a Iframe and below the iframe I am displaying two actions buttons the use case is the two actions should be displayed only when the user reaches the end of the iframe,So i am iframe inside a div.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery `offset()` or `position()` to get the bottom of the iframe.

http://api.jquery.com/position/

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: can you show any fiddle example for better clarification please